# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Todo>'

Tags: flutter, dart, dio, flutter-getx

I use dio with getx to get list of todo data but I see this message

> `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Todo>'`

when i go reach this line

List responseBode =  rsp.data['data'];

what is happen in this line and how to fix it , thanks

service class updated with converting to the list but still the same issue

1- the first class for controller
2- the second for the service class

```
class TodoListController extends GetxController {
  //var lstTask = List<dynamic>.empty(growable: true).obs;
  var items = List<Todo>.empty(growable: true).obs;

  var page = 1.obs;
  var totalRows = 10.obs;
  var isDataProcessing = false.obs;
  var isMoreDataAvailable = true.obs;
  var isSearching = false.obs;
  var isLoading = false.obs;
  var isCompleted = true.obs;

  var errorMsg = ''.obs ;
  var http = new HttpUtils();

  // For Pagination
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    // Fetch Data
    getTodo(page);

  }

  // Fetch Data
   getTodo(var page) {
    try {
      isMoreDataAvailable(false);
      isDataProcessing(true);
      AppServices().getTodo(page).then((resp) {
        isDataProcessing(false);
        resp.forEach(( dynamic json) {
          items.add(Todo.fromJson(json));
        });
        print(resp);
        //items.addAll(resp);
      }, onError: (err) {
        isDataProcessing(false);
        AppServices().showSnackBar("Error", err.toString(), Colors.red);
      });
    } catch (exception) {
      isDataProcessing(false);
      AppServices().showSnackBar("Exception", exception.toString(), Colors.red);
    }
  }

  // Get More data
   getMoreTodo(var page) {
    try {
        AppServices().getTodo(page).then((resp) {
        if (resp.length > 0) {
          isMoreDataAvailable(true);
        } else {
          isMoreDataAvailable(false);
          AppServices().showSnackBar("Message", "No more items", Colors.lightBlueAccent);
        }
        items.addAll(resp);
      }, onError: (err) {
        isMoreDataAvailable(false);
        AppServices().showSnackBar("Error", err.toString(), Colors.red);
      });
    } catch (exception) {
      isMoreDataAvailable(false);
      AppServices().showSnackBar("Exception", exception.toString(), Colors.red);
    }
  }
}
```

class AppServices extends GetConnect {
var http = new HttpUtils();

```
          // Fetch Data
  Future<List<Todo>> getTodo(var id) async {
    try {
      Response rsp =  await http.get(AppUrl.get_todo, {'current_page': id});
      print(rsp.data['data']);
      if (rsp.data["response_status"] != '400') {
        List<Todo> responseBode = rsp.data['data'].map ((todo) => Todo.fromJson(todo)).toList();
        return responseBode;
      } else {
        return rsp.data["response_message"] ;
      }
    }catch(exception)
    {
      return Future.error(exception.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the list of `dynamic` can't be automatically converted to a list of `Todo`'s.
You can convert the list like this:

```
 List<Todo> responseBode = rsp.data['data'].map ((todo) => Todo.fromJson(todo)).toList();
```

Then you can implement the Todo named contructor like this:

```
class Todo {
     //Your todo class
     String name;
      Todo.fromJson (data) {
          // conversion here
          name = data["name"] ?? null;
    }
}
```

Comment: still the same , still see the same exception

Comment: can you post the updated version of the code?

Comment: also i have a todo model

Answer (score 1):

This might be fixable with a simple type cast. I noticed you're using `Dio` with `GetConnect`. Nothing wrong with that per se but I can't imagine why you'd need both.

Since you're already in the GetX world here's how it would look just using GetConnect. This was how I could test because I'm not sure where `HttpUtils` comes from.

```
class AppServices extends GetConnect {
  // var http = new HttpUtils();

  // Fetch Data
  Future<List<Todo>> getTodo(var id) async {
    try {
      Response rsp = await httpClient.get(AppUrl.get_todo, {'current_page': id});
      print(rsp.body['data']);
      if (rsp.statusCode != 400) {
        List<Todo> responseBode = rsp.body['data'] as List<Todo>; // casting type here
        return responseBode;
      } else {
        return rsp.body["response_message"];
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      return Future.error(exception.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

If this doesn't work

```
List<Todo> responseBode = rsp.body['data'] as List<Todo>; // casting type here
```

Then you could also probably use return `Future<List>` instead.

Then that would turn the previous line into this

```
List responseBode = rsp.body['data'];
```

`GetConnect` handles json decoding for you so when using that, you don't need to manually do any more json work.

Edit: To answer your question in the comments about adding an auth to header in `GetConnect`:

You can do something like this.

```
final url = 'http://...'
 void _setUrl() {
    httpClient.baseUrl = url;
    httpClient.addRequestModifier((request) {
      request.headers['apikey'] = yourApiKey;
      return request;
    });
  }
```

After that you can just call

```
final response = await httpClient.get(url);
```

And your key will be in the url.

Then it returns a regular map and you're good to go.

Comment: thank you but this not working if remove this line because it is a dio wraper , var http = new HttpUtils(); i use dio because i have two questions about getconnect but no one example on the internet although i google it , 1- how to add basic auth to header , 2-how to pass many params to the same request

Comment: as you see here i have the ability to pass this 
get(AppUrl.get_todo, {'current_page': id})
and it will converted to http://example.com/todo_list?current_page=1

Comment: the json library returns a map which can’t be automatically casted to a class, you need a named constructor for that. At least as far as i know.

Comment: @Ale sorry I should clarified that json comment was specific to `GetConnect` which decodes the json itself and returns a regular map. I'll update the answer just for clarity. @user1080247 looks like you have a solution but see updated answer about adding auth in headers with `GetConnect`. I agree there is very little info out there about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use GetConnect without Dio.

Your AppServices would look Like:

```
Future<List<Todo>> getTodo(var id) async {
  final response =  await http.get(AppUrl.get_todo, query:{'current_page': id}, decoder: Todo.listFromJson);
  if(response.hasError){
    return Future.error(response.statusText);
   }
  return response.body;
}
```

Your model will look like:

```
class Todo {
 String name;
  Todo.fromJson (data) {
      name = data["name"] ?? null;
    }

 static List<Todo> listFromJson(dynamic str) => List<Todo>.from((str as List<dynamic>).map((x) => Todo.fromJson(x)));
}
```

Now it will directly return the List of Todo objects.

Usage might be something like this (in the controller):

```
final todoList = <Todo>[].obs; 

onInit()async{
 ...
 await getTodos();
}

Future<void> getTodos()async{
  try{
     final todos=await appServices.getTodo(1);
     todoList.assignAll(todos);
   } catch (e){
    // handle errors here. eg. show snackbar
   }
```